# Studying the function $f(x)=e^x+e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{3}}+\dots$

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $$f(x)=e^x+e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{3}}+\dots$$

Clearly, $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and $f'(0)=\infty$. However, $f''(0)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, This follows from the fact that $f''(x)|_{x=0}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$.

How does one study such a function? That is infinite everywhere, but has a finite second derivative?

Edit: I'm aware that a function needs to be finite for derivatives to be defined. However, dealing with this function purely algebraically, it is funny that it has a finite second derivative. Much like schemes were a counter-intuitive generalization of varieties, is it possible that there is a non-trivial generalization of functions (to include functions that are infinite on arbitrarily large subdomains) such that these derivatives could make sense, if only formally?

Comment: A "function" that is undefined does not have derivatives, even if a formal series development makes you think so. In the same vein, $\sum x^k$ is not $\frac1{1-x}$ when $|x|\ge1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust- I'm asking that if we could extend these definitions to include functions that map to $\infty$, what would be a reasonable way to study these functions?

Perhaps an example is ordinal numbers that were created to study infinite numbers in a systematic way.

Comment: @YvesDaoust- Note that in your example of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, all the derivatives of the function at $x=1$ are $\infty$. However here, we have that the second derivative is finite. This seems funny and counter-intuitive

Comment: My example did not intend to discuss this particular function. It was about the relevance of formal series.

Comment: The second derivative doesn't exist.

Comment: @YvesDaoust- I understand. I suppose I'm asking a different question from what you're answering. I'm aware of the standard facts that a function needs to be finite for derivatives to be defined, etc. I'm just talking about an interesting and counterintuitive phenomenon for this strange "function"

Comment: The domain of $f(x)$ should be $(-\infty,0)$ instead of $R$.

Comment: @xpaul- In fact the domain shouldn't be anything. This function is infinite for all negative values of $x$ as well.

Comment: Why don't you consider $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\left(e^{x/k}-1-x/k\right)$? Formally, it would give you the same second derivative, with the advantage that the function itself and its first derivative are well defined, too.

Comment: @user436658- That doesn't really answer the question. I'm not looking for a finite function that has this derivative. I'm just asking what it means for a function that is infinite everywhere to have a finite second derivative.